# UDP multithreaded echo server and client in java

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, echo, server

i'm trying to do a **UDP multithreaded echo server and client in java**
For now i have UDP echo server and client but without the multithreading part
This is my code:

Server:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class EchoServer implements Runnable 
{
    protected static DatagramSocket serverSocket;
    protected byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
    protected byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

    public EchoServer() throws SocketException{
        this.serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9876);

    }

    public void run() {
        try {
             while(true)
             {
                DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                String sentence = new String( receivePacket.getData());
                System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
                InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();
                int port = receivePacket.getPort();
                String capitalizedSentence = sentence.toUpperCase();
                sendData = capitalizedSentence.getBytes();
                DatagramPacket sendPacket =
                new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, port);
                serverSocket.send(sendPacket);
             }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //report exception somewhere.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
       {
        EchoServer ES = new EchoServer();
        ES.run();


       }

}
```

Client:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

class EchoClient
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
    {
       BufferedReader inFromUser =
          new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       DatagramSocket clientSocket = new DatagramSocket();
       InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
       byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
       byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
       String sentence = inFromUser.readLine();
       sendData = sentence.getBytes();
       DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length, IPAddress, 9876);
       clientSocket.send(sendPacket);
       DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
       clientSocket.receive(receivePacket);
       String modifiedSentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
       System.out.println("FROM SERVER:" + modifiedSentence);
       clientSocket.close();
    }
}
```

How do i turn it to work multithread??
Thanks :)

Comment: What design approaches have you looked into? Have you searched for multi-processing server models? Making a program multi-threaded is not like flipping a switch.

Comment: You don't need multithreading in a UDP Echo server. It's overkill. You also don't need to construct the reply packet. It's easier to reuse the request packet. It already has the reply address:port in it. Just reset the data. In the case of an echo server you don't even need to do that.